# Elasticsearch internal logs

Tags: docker, debugging, elasticsearch, kibana, serilog

My .NET core application writes logs to elasticsearch using the serilog elasticsearch sink. Elasticsearch + kibana run in a linux container on Windows 10 (using Docker desktop). In Kibana the log messages can be visualized. As longtime test, the application ran over night but on next day there were no data available in Kibana anymore. Is there any possibility to see what Elasticsearch is internally doing? Where is the internal Elasticsearch log information stored and how this can be accessed from the Windows 10 powershell?

Comment: "no data available in Kibana anymore". Are you sure the Kibana time frame(on right top corner) is set to 24H to confirm?

Comment: Thx for the hint. I see now some "old" logs (the newest from 2 am). But still dont know why elasticsearch stopped logging at some time (the serilog console sink is still writing logs).

Comment: No problem. I had the same issue, it was automatically set to 15m and my producer died in the middle of the night for some reason. Your logs should be there as ES does not include timeout for indexes to delete after a while(unlike Kafka). so it can be either the client or server connection died. good luck

Comment: I read that there is a default max.memory size that an elasticsearch container can have. How can be checked if this limit was eventually reached?

Comment: you can check the Monitoring tab(This feature is premium only, so you might start your 30day trial to see and use it.), but again change time frame to see longer periods. There you will be able to see the latency, heap size, resource usage, basically any health related information about any node of your cluster.